# How can I remove the password confirmation field in Gravity Forms User Registration in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the Gravity Forms User Registration plugin in a Wordpress site and the password field automatically includes a confirmation field (so the user has to input his password twice during registration). I am trying to remove the confirmation field so the user just enters his password once. Is there a way that I can remove the password confirmation field?

Link to plugin: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/category/user-registration/

Answer (score 0):

To create a single password input field, use a standard text field, then in the "Advanced" tab for that field, check "Enable Password Input".  You can then map that field to Password in the User Registration settings.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me with the most recent version. User Registration doesn't let a text > password enabled field to be mapped to the password.